# ng-show ng-clicks in angularjs directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to solve a problem I am having at the moment.

I have a view a directive and a directive template that is called using templateurl.

My template works fine through the directive and I can see it in my view; however some functions dont work.

For example, the template called by my directive has a ng-show="toShow()", this isn't working. toShow(inDate,outDate) is a function inside my directive it returns false or true depending on the data that is passed to it.

How can it make the template of my directive work in the same manner as it was a tempalte created inside my view?

Thank you

EDIT:

```
<div class="custom-slider row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="base">
        <span ng-repeat="b in Months track by $index" rc-selection s-date="b.fromDate"
              e-date="b.toDate" period-type="b.periodType.name">
        </span>
    </div>
```

//DIRECTIVE

```
app.directive('rcSelection', function ($document, $window, $filter) {
    return {
        scope: {
            sDate: '=',
            eDate: '=',
            periodType: '=',            
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {}
            scope.$watch('sDate', function (sDate) {
                scope.$watch('eDate', function (eDate) {
                    scope.$watch('periodType', function (periodType) {

                        if (angular.isUndefined(sDate)) {
                        } else {
                            dateRangesVisulization(sDate, eDate, periodType, element, scope);                           
                            element.bind('click', function (event) {
                                toggleDateRange(element, sDate, eDate)
                                methodTest(scope)
                            });
                        }

                    },true);
                }, true);
            }, true);
            }

        },

        templateUrl:'partials/pathToTemplate.html'
    };

    function toShow(){
    return true or false;
    }


    ----------


    /*Template*/
    <span id="selection"
          style="width:{{selWidth}}px;margin-left:{{marginLeft}}px;position:absolute;padding:0;background-color: {{color}}">
        <span class="dateContent">{{initialDate}}</span>
        <span  ng-show="toShow(sDate,eDate)" class="dateContentBottom">{{endDate}}</span>
    </span>
```

Comment: can you upload the code? jsfiddle would even be better.

Comment: there's a lot of code to upload and unfortunately because of how the view-directive-directive template works it's not possible for me to upload a working version of the code on here. I'll try to set something up and see if it works

Comment: Where do you declare your toShow function in your directive ? It should be in the scope of the associated controller.

Comment: in my directive I have
templateUrl:"parthtoTemplate"
pathtoTemplate has a div with ng-show in it
The view calls the directive which then returns the template
but it doesn't work.
In the template, do I have to define the controller as well? doesn't the template get automatically assigned to the controller of the view that is calling the directive?
My functions are also in the directive so does it matter whether the controller is involved?

Comment: Without code we can't help much - my best guess is that the function toShow is not attached to scope, i.e. function should be `scope.toShow = function...` inside the directive.

Comment: I have edited my post and added some code, I hope this can help. thank you